# Azure SQL database failover

Tags: sql-server, azure

We are looking at setting up a high availability solution for a web application using Azure.

Azure SQL database has the Geo-Replication options to sync data to secondary copies of the database in a separate region.

If there is a failure in the primary region does the Azure SQL database automatically fail over to the secondary or is this something that has to be 
done manually or by a custom monitoring tool not provided by Azure?

Thanks for your help
Gavin

Answer (score 0):

It is provided by Azure automatically

Reference:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/fault-tolerance-in-windows-azure-sql-database/